# Overdetermined System Ax=b

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's say we have the following system of equations:
\begin{equation}
A{\bf x}={\bf b} \qquad (1)
\end{equation}
where $A$ is  $N \times 4$, $\mathbf{x}$ is  $4 \times 1$ (unknowns) and ${\bf b}$ is $N \times 1$.

Using linear-least square method the solution of the overdetermined system is:

\begin{equation}
(A^TA) {\bf x} = A^T {\bf b} \qquad (2)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
{\bf x} = (A^TA)^{-1} A^T {\bf b} \qquad (3)
\end{equation}

Why do we multiply both sides of Eq.$(1)$ by $A^T$?

Comment: You only do this when $A$ has full row rank. Then you do it because $A^TA$ is invertable. Otherwise you do something different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You minimize the the (squared) expression $V=\left\| Ax-b \right\|^2$. This is equal to

$V=(Ax-b)^T(Ax-b)$

Remove $T$ from the brackets. The order of $Ax$ is changing.

$V=(x^TA^T-b^T)(Ax-b)$

Multiplying out the brackets.

$V=x^TA^TAx-x^TA^Tb-b^TAx+b^Tb$

$x^TA^Tb$ and $b^TAx$ are both scalars and they are equal. One can be replaced by another.

$V=x^TA^TAx-2x^TA^Tb+b^Tb$

To optimize this expression w.r.t $x$ it has to be calculated the derivative w.r.t $x $ and set it equal to zero. The derivative of $b^Tb$ is zero, because it has no $x$.

$\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}=2A^TAx-2A^Tb=0 \quad |:2$

$A^TAx-A^Tb=0 \quad \quad$

$A^TAx=A^Tb \quad\quad |:A^TA $

> On the LHS $A^TA$ is **left** from $x$. If we divide both sides by
>   $(A^TA)^{}$ then $(A^TA)^{-1}$ has to be **left** on the RHS as well.

$\boxed{x=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb}$

Comment: Great explanation thank you so much

Comment: You´re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Linear least square problem solves the probelm $$\min \frac{1}{2}\left\| Ax-b \right\|^2$$

To solve the problem, we differentiate with respect to $x$ and equare it to zero and we end up with

$$A^T(Ax-b)=0$$

Comment: Can you explain how did you find the $A^T$? Why it's not (Ax-b)A=0?

Comment: @callculus did a great job!

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the linear system
$$
\mathbf{A}x = b
$$
has no solution and that the data vector $b\notin\mathcal{N}\left( \mathcal{A} \right).$

There is no exact solution because the data vector $b$ is not in the column space of $\mathbf{A}$.

One path to solution involves formulating a problem with the same solution that does have a solution. This is the normal equations.
$$
\mathbf{A}^{*}\mathbf{A}x = \mathbf{A}^{*}b.
$$
The vector on the right, $\mathbf{A}^{*}b$ is clearly in the column space of $\mathcal{A}^{*}$. In fact we are given the prescription for combining the column vectors
$$
 b_{1} \left[ \mathbf{A}^{*} \right]_{1} + 
 b_{2} \left[ \mathbf{A}^{*} \right]_{2} + \dots
 b_{m} \left[ \mathbf{A}^{*} \right]_{m}.
$$

Now we can use tools like Gaussian elimination and $\mathbf{L}\mathbf{U}$ decomposition to solve the problem.

In numerical problems, the normal equations can be a poor choice and benefit from methods like the $\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{R}$ and singular value decompositions.